# Same operation with einsum and tensordot with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Let's say I have two 3D arrays `A` and `B`of shape `(3, 4, N)` and `(4, 3, N)`.

I can compute the dot product between slices along the third axis with

```
with_einsum = np.eisum('ikl,kjl->ijl', A, B)
```

Is it possible to perform the same operation with `numpy.tensordot` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `np.einsum('ikl,kjl->ijl', A, B)`, there is axis alignment requirement with string - `l` that stays with the inputs and the output. As such, using `np.tensordot` might not necessarily result in performance improvement, but since the question has specifically asked for it, let's suggest it anyway. Now, `np.tensordot` would spread out the axes that don't take part in sum-reduction as separate axes, resulting in `(N,N)`. So, to get to the final output, we need to extract the elements along the diagonal of the spread-out axes.

Here's how a solution with `np.tensordot` would look like -

```
mask = np.eye(N,dtype=bool)
out = np.tensordot(A,B,axes=((1),(0))).swapaxes(1,2)[:,:,mask]
```

There would be cases where `np.dot/np.tensordot` might come out as winner, but that requires that the sum-reduction axes have decent lengths. See [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41443497/3293881) for a more detailed analysis.

For the  given problem, that's not the case as the length of sum-reduction is just `4`. So, I would think `einsum` would be best here!

Comment: So, in case of an axis which does not take part in the operation (i.e. we just perform the same operation along slices along this axis), `np.einsum` is the most suited function?

Comment: @floflo29 Linked another post which should shed more info on it. Check that out too!

Comment: Is there a generic way to algebraically write the expression computed with `np.einsum`? I will also give a look at your link!

Comment: @floflo29 Not sure what you mean by writing algebraically. Could you elaborate? I would think that the string notation used by `einsum` is pretty close how one would implement in a loopy way and as such is pretty intuitive, once we get to know what each string means.

Comment: For example, if we have `C=np.einsum('ikl,kjl->ijl', A, B)` we can write it: C(i,j,l) = sum(k)A(i,k,l)*B(k,j,l)

Comment: @floflo29 I see. Sadly, there isn't any, sorry.