# Understanding tensordot

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, tensor, dot-product

After I learned how to use `einsum`, I am now trying to understand how `np.tensordot` works.

However, I am a little bit lost especially regarding the various possibilities for the parameter `axes`.

To understand it, as I have never practiced tensor calculus, I use the following example:

```
A = np.random.randint(2, size=(2, 3, 5))
B = np.random.randint(2, size=(3, 2, 4))
```

In this case, what are the different possible `np.tensordot` and how would you compute it manually?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The idea with `tensordot` is pretty simple - We input the arrays and the respective axes along which the sum-reductions are intended. The axes that take part in sum-reduction are removed in the output and all of the remaining axes from the input arrays are *spread-out* as different axes in the output keeping the order in which the input arrays are fed.

Let's look at few sample cases with one and two axes of sum-reductions and also swap the input places and see how the order is kept in the output.

### I. One axis of sum-reduction

Inputs :

```
 In [7]: A = np.random.randint(2, size=(2, 6, 5))
   ...:  B = np.random.randint(2, size=(3, 2, 4))
   ...:
```

Case #1:

```
In [9]: np.tensordot(A, B, axes=((0),(1))).shape
Out[9]: (6, 5, 3, 4)

A : (2, 6, 5) -> reduction of axis=0
B : (3, 2, 4) -> reduction of axis=1

Output : `(2, 6, 5)`, `(3, 2, 4)` ===(2 gone)==> `(6,5)` + `(3,4)` => `(6,5,3,4)`
```

Case #2 (same as case #1 but the inputs are fed swapped):

```
In [8]: np.tensordot(B, A, axes=((1),(0))).shape
Out[8]: (3, 4, 6, 5)

B : (3, 2, 4) -> reduction of axis=1
A : (2, 6, 5) -> reduction of axis=0

Output : `(3, 2, 4)`, `(2, 6, 5)` ===(2 gone)==> `(3,4)` + `(6,5)` => `(3,4,6,5)`.
```

### II. Two axes of sum-reduction

Inputs :

```
In [11]: A = np.random.randint(2, size=(2, 3, 5))
    ...: B = np.random.randint(2, size=(3, 2, 4))
    ...:
```

Case #1:

```
In [12]: np.tensordot(A, B, axes=((0,1),(1,0))).shape
Out[12]: (5, 4)

A : (2, 3, 5) -> reduction of axis=(0,1)
B : (3, 2, 4) -> reduction of axis=(1,0)

Output : `(2, 3, 5)`, `(3, 2, 4)` ===(2,3 gone)==> `(5)` + `(4)` => `(5,4)`
```

Case #2:

```
In [14]: np.tensordot(B, A, axes=((1,0),(0,1))).shape
Out[14]: (4, 5)

B : (3, 2, 4) -> reduction of axis=(1,0)
A : (2, 3, 5) -> reduction of axis=(0,1)

Output : `(3, 2, 4)`, `(2, 3, 5)` ===(2,3 gone)==> `(4)` + `(5)` => `(4,5)`
```

We can extend this to as many axes as possible.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by sum-reduction?

Comment: @floflo29 Well you might know that matrix-multiplication involves elementwise multiplication keeping an axis aligned and then summation of elements along that common aligned axis. With that summation, we are losing that common axis, which is termed as reduction, so in short sum-reduction.

Comment: I've made "experimentations" in comparing `np.einsum` and `np.tensordot` and I think I now do understand how it works.

Comment: Is there anyway to reorder the output axes? Just use `transpose` at the end?

Comment: @BryanHead The only way to reorder the output axes using `np.tensordot` is to swap the inputs. If it doesn't get you your desired one, `transpose` would be the way to go.

Comment: Maybe for completeness and for newbies like me, would it be a good idea to mention that the *dimensions of the axes* to be sum-reduced **must** match? Although it's obvious from your examples, but stating it explicitly is really good :) This shape match constraint is well explained in TF docstring of `tf.tensordot`. Also, TF uses the term *contraction* or *tensor contraction*, so it might be a good idea to add that as well

Comment: Would have been better if @Divakar have added the example starting from 1-D tensor along with how each entry is computed. E.g. `t1=K.variable([[1,2],[2,3]] )
t2=K.variable([2,3])
print(K.eval(tf.tensordot(t1,t2,axes=0)))` output: `[[[2. 3.]
  [4. 6.]]

 [[4. 6.]
  [6. 9.]]]` Not sure how the output shape is `2x2x2`.

Comment: @chandresh Your query seems to be tensorflow specific. `numpy.tensordot` is specific to NumPy arrays. So, please post a question with the appropriate tag, if you have any.

Comment: @Divakar both work the same way if you just change tf variables to np variables. see here [tf.tensordot](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot)

Comment: It would be better to show actual math behind each operation, not only shapes

Comment: @dereks You are looking to learn how sum-reductions are done? That's too-broad and beyond the scope. For the same, one can can lookup matrix-multiplication.

Comment: I understand matmul, einsum and dot product. But like the author of this question I don't know how to use tensordot.

Comment: @dereks So, when you are talking about math, I understood you are looking to understand sum-reductions. If not, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for a few complete examples of using `tensordot`. All steps (all operations inside) from the beginning to the end with different `axes` argument.

Comment: @dereks Yeah I am expecting readers to know how matrix-multiplication works and what are sum-reductions. Hence, examples are listed in this post with respect to shapes and how the axes are aligned.

Comment: How matrix-multiplication works: `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Jmb3q-kvNTr1Lz3jgmIIxiPo_GGgwllP_FonFnSROmte0wc1KmM7d_aUJhHzPDsA7wB0es5OTHs51HSSlENTOltoa31TxzZMZlgGpf-l62gCHRaU3C_CsHUWw3orAOLCM5Lucpo` What does this have to do with `tensordot`?

Comment: Sum-reduction: `print(f"{tf.einsum('ij->j', A)}\t tf.reduce_sum(A, 0)\t- Column sum")`

Comment: @dereks The sum-reduction term used in this post is an umbrella term for element-wise multiplication and then sum-reduction. In the context of dot/tensordot, I assumed it would be safe to put it that way. Apologies if that was confusing. Now, with matrix-multiplication you have one axis of sum-reduction (second axis of first array against first axis of second array), whereas in tensordot more than one axes of sum-reduction. The examples presented show how axes are aligned in the input arrays and how the output axes are obtained from those.

Comment: @Divakar Thank you. Your comments were helpful. I added what I meant as the answer below.

Comment: _"all of the remaining axes from the input arrays are spread-out"_  This is exactly what I missed... now I have just to understand how to reduce the dimensionality of `tensordot` output when in `einsum` I use a repeated index in both inputs and the output — I know of [this answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41848632/2749397) but I still haven't grasped the process, maybe you could try to answer [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357297/python-tensor-matrix-multiply) using `tensordot`.  In any case, thank you.

Comment: @gboffi Well `tensordot` won't work there, because we need to keep one axis aligned through the inputs and also keep that in output - `i`. So, einsum is the way to go there.

Answer (score 9):

`tensordot` swaps axes and reshapes the inputs so it can apply `np.dot` to 2 2d arrays. It then swaps and reshapes back to the target. It may be easier to experiment than to explain. There's no special tensor math going on, just extending `dot` to work in higher dimensions. `tensor` just means arrays with more than 2d.  If you are already comfortable with `einsum` then it will be simplest compare the results to that.

A sample test, summing on 1 pair of axes

```
In [823]: np.tensordot(A,B,[0,1]).shape
Out[823]: (3, 5, 3, 4)
In [824]: np.einsum('ijk,lim',A,B).shape
Out[824]: (3, 5, 3, 4)
In [825]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ijk,lim',A,B),np.tensordot(A,B,[0,1]))
Out[825]: True
```

another, summing on two.

```
In [826]: np.tensordot(A,B,[(0,1),(1,0)]).shape
Out[826]: (5, 4)
In [827]: np.einsum('ijk,jim',A,B).shape
Out[827]: (5, 4)
In [828]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ijk,jim',A,B),np.tensordot(A,B,[(0,1),(1,0)]))
Out[828]: True
```

We could do same with the `(1,0)` pair.  Given the mix of dimension I don't think there's another combination.

Comment: I still don't fully grasp it :(. In the 1st example from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) they are multiplying element-wise 2 arrays with shape `(4,3)` and then doing `sum` over those 2 axes. How could you get that same result using a `dot` product?

Comment: The way I could reproduce the 1st result from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) is by using `np.dot` on *flattened* 2-D arrays: `for aa in a.T:
    for bb in b.T:
        print(aa.ravel().dot(bb.T.ravel()))`

Comment: The `einsum` equivalent of `tensordot` with `axes=([1,0],[0,1])`, is `np.einsum('ijk,jil->kl',a,b)`.  This `dot` also does it: `a.T.reshape(5,12).dot(b.reshape(12,2))`.  The `dot` is between a (5,12) and (12,2).  The `a.T` puts the 5 first, and also swaps the (3,4) to match `b`.

Answer (score 6):

The answers above are great and helped me a lot in understanding `tensordot`. But they don't show actual math behind operations. That's why I did equivalent operations in TF 2 for myself and decided to share them here:

```
a = tf.constant([1,2.])
b = tf.constant([2,3.])
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, 0)}\t tf.einsum('i,j', a, b)\t\t- ((the last 0 axes of a), (the first 0 axes of b))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, ((),()))}\t tf.einsum('i,j', a, b)\t\t- ((() axis of a), (() axis of b))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(b, a, 0)}\t tf.einsum('i,j->ji', a, b)\t- ((the last 0 axes of b), (the first 0 axes of a))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, 1)}\t\t tf.einsum('i,i', a, b)\t\t- ((the last 1 axes of a), (the first 1 axes of b))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, ((0,), (0,)))}\t\t tf.einsum('i,i', a, b)\t\t- ((0th axis of a), (0th axis of b))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, (0,0))}\t\t tf.einsum('i,i', a, b)\t\t- ((0th axis of a), (0th axis of b))")

[[2. 3.]
 [4. 6.]]    tf.einsum('i,j', a, b)     - ((the last 0 axes of a), (the first 0 axes of b))
[[2. 3.]
 [4. 6.]]    tf.einsum('i,j', a, b)     - ((() axis of a), (() axis of b))
[[2. 4.]
 [3. 6.]]    tf.einsum('i,j->ji', a, b) - ((the last 0 axes of b), (the first 0 axes of a))
8.0          tf.einsum('i,i', a, b)     - ((the last 1 axes of a), (the first 1 axes of b))
8.0          tf.einsum('i,i', a, b)     - ((0th axis of a), (0th axis of b))
8.0          tf.einsum('i,i', a, b)     - ((0th axis of a), (0th axis of b))
```

And for `(2,2)` shape:

```
a = tf.constant([[1,2],
                 [-2,3.]])

b = tf.constant([[-2,3],
                 [0,4.]])
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, 0)}\t tf.einsum('ij,kl', a, b)\t- ((the last 0 axes of a), (the first 0 axes of b))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, (0,0))}\t tf.einsum('ij,ik', a, b)\t- ((0th axis of a), (0th axis of b))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, (0,1))}\t tf.einsum('ij,ki', a, b)\t- ((0th axis of a), (1st axis of b))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, 1)}\t tf.matmul(a, b)\t\t- ((the last 1 axes of a), (the first 1 axes of b))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, ((1,), (0,)))}\t tf.einsum('ij,jk', a, b)\t- ((1st axis of a), (0th axis of b))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, (1, 0))}\t tf.matmul(a, b)\t\t- ((1st axis of a), (0th axis of b))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, 2)}\t tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(a, b))\t- ((the last 2 axes of a), (the first 2 axes of b))")
print(f"{tf.tensordot(a, b, ((0,1), (0,1)))}\t tf.einsum('ij,ij->', a, b)\t\t- ((0th axis of a, 1st axis of a), (0th axis of b, 1st axis of b))")
[[[[-2.  3.]
   [ 0.  4.]]
  [[-4.  6.]
   [ 0.  8.]]]

 [[[ 4. -6.]
   [-0. -8.]]
  [[-6.  9.]
   [ 0. 12.]]]]  tf.einsum('ij,kl', a, b)   - ((the last 0 axes of a), (the first 0 axes of b))
[[-2. -5.]
 [-4. 18.]]      tf.einsum('ij,ik', a, b)   - ((0th axis of a), (0th axis of b))
[[-8. -8.]
 [ 5. 12.]]      tf.einsum('ij,ki', a, b)   - ((0th axis of a), (1st axis of b))
[[-2. 11.]
 [ 4.  6.]]      tf.matmul(a, b)            - ((the last 1 axes of a), (the first 1 axes of b))
[[-2. 11.]
 [ 4.  6.]]      tf.einsum('ij,jk', a, b)   - ((1st axis of a), (0th axis of b))
[[-2. 11.]
 [ 4.  6.]]      tf.matmul(a, b)            - ((1st axis of a), (0th axis of b))
16.0    tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(a, b))    - ((the last 2 axes of a), (the first 2 axes of b))
16.0    tf.einsum('ij,ij->', a, b)          - ((0th axis of a, 1st axis of a), (0th axis of b, 1st axis of b))
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides the above answers, it would be easier to understand **np.tensordot** if breaking it down into nested loops:

Assume:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
b = np.arange(30).reshape(3,5,2)
```

Then **a** is

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

and **b** is

```
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9]],

       [[10, 11],
        [12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17],
        [18, 19]],

       [[20, 21],
        [22, 23],
        [24, 25],
        [26, 27],
        [28, 29]]])
```

Let

```
c = np.tensordot(a, b, axes=([0,1],[2,0]))
```

which is equivalent to

```
c = np.zeros((4,5))
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(5):
        for p in range(2):
            for q in range(3):
                c[i,j] += a[p,q,i] * b[q,j,p]
```

The axes having the same dimensions (here are 2 and 3) in both tensors can be reduced by the sum over them. And the parameter **axes**=([0,1],[2,0]) is same as **axes**=([1,0],[0,2]).

The final **c** is

```
array([[ 808,  928, 1048, 1168, 1288],
       [ 871, 1003, 1135, 1267, 1399],
       [ 934, 1078, 1222, 1366, 1510],
       [ 997, 1153, 1309, 1465, 1621]])
```