# Vectorise sequential numpy calculations

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a number of operations in numpy which I can perfectly perform in a loop, but I haven't been able to vectorise them in one numpy call.

```
# data matrix
d = np.random.rand(1496, 1, 2)

# boolean matrix
r = np.random.rand(5, 1496, 1, 2) > 0.5

# result matrix
x = np.empty((5,))

# How can I avoid this loop?
for i in xrange(r.shape[0]):
  x[i] = d[r[i]].sum()
```

Is it possible to speed things up by somehow vectorising the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize it as this; since `d` is one dimension less than `r`, when they are multiplied, `d` will be broadcasted along `axis=0` of `r` and so avoid the loop; And also since `r` is a boolean array, `d[r].sum()` will be the same as `(d*r).sum`:

```
(d * r).sum(axis=(1,2,3))
# array([ 775.17049697,  728.61537246,  735.05686655,  765.19469927,
#         759.44834287])
```

The result is the same as `x`:

```
((d*r).sum(axis=(1,2,3)) == x).all()
# True
```

Comment: Nice idea to multiply the float and boolean matrix and use broadcasting (also thanks for the explanation).

Comment: No problems. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 2):

A variation of the @Psidom approach:

```
np.tensordot(d, r, axes=((0,1,2), (1,2,3)))
```

This relies on `tensordot` function. From its [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html#numpy.tensordot):

> Given two tensors (arrays of dimension greater than or equal to one), `a` and `b`, and an array_like object containing two array_like objects, `(a_axes, b_axes)`, sum the products of `a`'s and `b`'s elements (components) over the axes specified by `a_axes` and `b_axes`.

Fundamentally, `tensordot` computes the product of two arrays (just like @Psidom did) and computes the sum of all elements of the product array. The only "advantage" of this method over @Psidom's approach is that it allows more flexibility in specifying over which axes to perform product and summation *in both arrays*. It does not offer improved performance over @Psidom's method.

Also, see [Understanding tensordot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/understanding-tensordot).

Comment: Interesting approach. Could you explain it a bit? Would this be faster than @Psidom's suggestion?