# Leaving dimension unaffected with numpy tensordot

Tags: python, numpy

I've been using `np.tensordot` in the past without any problems, but my current example, I struggle to understand the result.

For `np.tensordot(d * y, r, axes=((1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4))).shape`, I would expect a shape of `(6, 5)`, but instead, I get `(6, 6, 5)`. When I would run `tensordot` 6 times on axis0, I would however get the expected result, but I'd rather have `tensordot` do this for me in one call. What's wrong with this?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = np.random.rand(6, 7, 1, 2)
>>> y = np.random.rand(6, 7, 1, 2)
>>> r = np.random.rand(6, 5, 7, 1, 2) > 0.5
>>> 
>>> np.tensordot(d * y, r, axes=((1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4))).shape
(6, 6, 5)
>>> np.tensordot((d * y)[0], r[0], axes=((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3))).shape
(5,)
>>> np.tensordot((d * y)[1], r[1], axes=((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3))).shape
(5,)
>>> np.tensordot((d * y)[2], r[2], axes=((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3))).shape
(5,)
...
>>> np.tensordot((d * y)[5], r[5], axes=((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3))).shape
(5,)
```

Comment: [`Understanding tensordot`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41870228) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simpler case:

```
In [709]: d=np.ones((6,2));
In [710]: np.tensordot(d,d,axes=(1,1)).shape
Out[710]: (6, 6)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
In [712]: np.einsum('ij,kj->ik',d,d).shape
Out[712]: (6, 6)
```

This isn't `ij,ij->i`. It's a outer product on the unlisted axes, not an element by element one.

You have `(6, 7, 1, 2)` and `(6, 5, 7, 1, 2)`, and want to sum on (7,1,2).  It's doing an outer product on the (6) and (6,5).

`np.einsum('i...,ij...->ij',d,r)` would do, I think, what you want.

Under the covers, `tensordot` reshapes and swaps axes so that the problem becomes a 2d `np.dot` call.  Then it reshapes and swaps back as needed.

---

Correction; I can't use ellipsis for the 'dotted' dimensions

```
In [726]: np.einsum('aijk,abijk->ab',d,r).shape
Out[726]: (6, 5)
```

and method:

```
In [729]: (d[:,None,...]*r).sum(axis=(2,3,4)).shape
Out[729]: (6, 5)
```

### timings

```
In [734]: timeit [np.tensordot(d[i],r[i], axes=((0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3))) for i in 
     ...: range(6)]
145 µs ± 514 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [735]: timeit np.einsum('aijk,abijk->ab',d,r)
7.22 µs ± 34.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [736]: timeit (d[:,None,...]*r).sum(axis=(2,3,4))
16.6 µs ± 84.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Another solution, using the `@` (matmul) operator

```
In [747]: timeit np.squeeze(d.reshape(6,1,14)@r.reshape(6,5,14).transpose(0,2,1))
11.4 µs ± 28.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the `einsum` syntax, but your suggestions raises an Exception: `ValueError: output has more dimensions than subscripts given in einstein sum, but no '...' ellipsis provided to broadcast the extra dimensions.`

Comment: Thanks for the two methods and the explanation about `tensordot`. Which would you think works faster given the dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

In `tensordot`, every axis is either:

- summed over (contracted) and thus eliminated from the final result, or
- unaffected (and unconstrained) and appears exactly once in the summation.

So when you write `tensordot(d * y, r, axes=((1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)))`, you are calculating:

```
T[i j k] = ∑[l m n] dy[i l m n] r[j k l m n]
```

where `dy ≡ d * y`.  What you *want* to calculate is

```
T[i k] = ∑[l m n] dy[i l m n] r[i k l m n]
```

Notice that `i` appears twice, yet isn't being summed over.  This means `i` is actually *constrained* here (think of it as an implicit Kronecker delta).  Hence, this isn't something that `tensordot` can do all by itself.

The simplest way is to use `einsum` and just explicitly declare what you want:

```
np.einsum("i l m n, i k l m n -> i k", d * y, r)
```

Since `einsum` can see the entire expression you're trying to calculate, it should be able to find a relatively optimal way to perform this calculation.

Comment: So really the reason why `tensordot` cannot derive the expected result is that it can't deal with what you called a "constrained" axes, one that isn't summed over. This is also the reason why the problem disappeared when I explicitly selected the unaffected dimension (axis0) in the loop...?

Comment: Yeah, when you explicitly specify one of the indices, the index is no longer under `tensordot`'s control anymore, so you can do whatever you want with it.