# Double dot product with broadcasting in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, tensor

I have the following operation :

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(3,5,5)
w = np.random.rand(5,5)

y=np.zeros((3,5,5))
for i in range(3):
    y[i] = np.dot(w.T,np.dot(x[i],w))
```

Which corresponds to the pseudo-expression `y[m,i,j] = sum( w[k,i] * x[m,k,l] * w[l,j], axes=[k,l]` or equivalently simply the dot product of `w.T` , `x`, `w` broadcaster over the first dimension of `x`.

How can I implement it with numpy's broadcasting rules ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach with [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) which should be better than `broadcasting + summation` anyday -

```
# Take care of "np.dot(x[i],w)" term
x_w = np.tensordot(x,w,axes=((2),(0)))

# Perform "np.dot(w.T,np.dot(x[i],w))" : "np.dot(w.T,x_w)"
y_out = np.tensordot(x_w,w,axes=((1),(0))).swapaxes(1,2)
```

Alternatively, all of the *mess* being taken care of with one [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) call, but could be slower -

```
y_out = np.einsum('ab,cae,eg->cbg',w,x,w)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [114]: def tensordot_app(x, w):
     ...:     x_w = np.tensordot(x,w,axes=((2),(0)))
     ...:     return np.tensordot(x_w,w,axes=((1),(0))).swapaxes(1,2)
     ...: 
     ...: def einsum_app(x, w):
     ...:     return np.einsum('ab,cae,eg->cbg',w,x,w)
     ...: 

In [115]: x = np.random.rand(30,50,50)
     ...: w = np.random.rand(50,50)
     ...: 

In [116]: %timeit tensordot_app(x, w)
1000 loops, best of 3: 477 µs per loop

In [117]: %timeit einsum_app(x, w)
1 loop, best of 3: 219 ms per loop
```

---

**Giving the broadcasting a chance**

The sum-notation was -

```
y[m,i,j] = sum( w[k,i] * x[m,k,l] * w[l,j], axes=[k,l] )
```

Thus, the three terms would be stacked for broadcasting, like so -

```
w : [ N x k x i x N x N]
x : [ m x k x N x l x N]
w : [ N x N X N x l x j]
```

, where `N` represents new-axis being appended to facilitate `broadcasting` along those dims.

The terms with new axes being added with `None/np.newaxis` would then look like this -

```
w : w[None, :,    :,    None, None]
x : x[:,    :,    None, :,    None]
w : w[None, None, None, :,       :]
```

Thus, the broadcasted product would be -

```
p = w[None,:,:,None,None]*x[:,:,None,:,None]*w[None,None,None,:,:]
```

Finally, the output would be sum-reduction to lose `(k,l)`, i.e. axes =`(1,3)` -

```
y = p.sum((1,3))
```

Comment: Cool ! I know `tensordot`is faster for dot products than broadcasting, but wouldn't a single sum + broadcasting be faster than two `tensordots`?

Comment: Also, do you know any reference where it is clearly explained how to convert a given tensor operation, expressed with indices, into a numpy sum-broadcasting operation ? 
I know a little about how to do it but I can't figure out a general way to proceed :)

Comment: @Tool Tensordot avoids the expansion and does the sum-reduction through BLAS calls, and as such are much faster than broadcasting + sum-reductions.

Comment: @Tool There isn't a general way. We need to keep track of the axes that are undergoing sum-reductions and use those under the axes arg for `np.tensordot`. I can at least point to another Q&A that sort of explains using `tensordot` if you are having trouble understanding it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/

Comment: Thank you for this reference (I knew it but I'll need to read it again). I may have expressed myself badly, I am looking for a general way to bridge from a given mathematical tensor operation to the equivalent numpy implementation with broadcasting-sum-reductions, since I think every given tensor operation can be implemented this way.
I'll probably post a new question for this purpose, as it may be clearer.

Comment: @Tool In the broadcasted form, you have stated : `sum(w[k,i]*x[k,l]*w[l,j],axes=[k,l])`. But `x` is 3D there.

Comment: The correct pseudo-expression is `y[m,i,j] = sum( w[k,i] * x[m,k,l] * w[l,j], axes=[k,l]`. I've corrected the post as well

Comment: That is exactly the methodology I was looking for ! Very neat, thanks.