# Achieving batch matrix multiply using tensordot

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to achieve the same behaviour as np.matmul parallel matrix multiplication using just tensordot,dot and reshaping etc.

The library I am translating this to using does not have a matmul that supports parallel multiplication, only dot and tensordot.

Additionally I want to avoid iterating over the first dimension, and want to do this using a set of matrix multiplications and reshaping (want as much of it to run using BLAS/GPU as i have large numbers of small matrices to calculate in parallel).

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

angles = np.array([np.pi/4, 2*np.pi/4, 2*np.pi/4])

vectors = np.array([ [1,0],[1,-1],[-1,0]])

s = np.sin(angles)
c = np.cos(angles)

rotations = np.array([[c,s],[-s,c]]).T

print rotations

print vectors

print("Correct: %s" % np.matmul(rotations, vectors.reshape(3,2,1)))

# I want to do this using tensordot/reshaping, i.e just gemm BLAS operations underneath
print("Wrong: %s" % np.tensordot(rotations, vectors, axes=(1,1)))
```

The output of this is:

```
Correct: [[[  7.07106781e-01]
  [  7.07106781e-01]]

 [[  1.00000000e+00]
  [  1.00000000e+00]]

 [[ -6.12323400e-17]
  [ -1.00000000e+00]]]


Wrong: [[[  7.07106781e-01   1.11022302e-16  -7.07106781e-01]
  [ -7.07106781e-01  -1.41421356e+00   7.07106781e-01]]

 [[  6.12323400e-17  -1.00000000e+00  -6.12323400e-17]
  [ -1.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]

 [[  6.12323400e-17  -1.00000000e+00  -6.12323400e-17]
  [ -1.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]]
```

Is there a way in which I can modify the second expression in order to get the same result as the first, just using dot/tensordot.

I believe it is possible, and have seen [some comments online](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/58p6x0/a_parallel_einsum/d94u04a/), but never any examples

Comment: `tensordot` swaps and reshapes so the problem reduces to a `dot` (and then back).  Some `matmul` operations can be achieved by taking a diagonal from a much larger 'outer' calculation.

Comment: yes, I did notice that taking the diagonal, but thinking that would potentially be far less efficient then just looping

Answer (score 4):

We need to keep one aligned and keep that also at the output. So, `tensordot/dot` won't work here. [`More info on tensordot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/understanding-tensordot) might explain it somehow on why it won't. But, we can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which in most cases (in my experience) is seen to be marginally faster than `np.matmul`.

The implementation would look something like this -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',rotations, vectors)
```

Also, it seems the desired output has one trailing singleton dim. So, append a new axis there with `None/np.newaxis`, like so -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',rotations, vectors)[...,None]
```

Comment: "The library I am translating this to using does not have a matmul that supports parallel multiplication, only dot and tensordot. " - I cannot use einsum either. Any other ideas?

Comment: @ChrisBamford What library is it? Is it tensorflow?

Comment: @ChrisBamford Nah, it's not possible with `dot/tensordot` in a vectorized manner. So, I would say just loop through.