# too many indices for array when using np.where

Tags: python, numpy, indices

I have the code:

```
a=b=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
c=np.zeros(3)

for x in range(3):
    c[x]=np.average(b[np.where(a<x+3)])
```

The output of `c` is

`>>>array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ])`

Instead of the for loop, I wanna use array (vectorization), then I did the following code:

```
a=b=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
c=np.zeros(3)
i=np.arange(3)
c[i]=np.average(b[np.where(a<i[:,None,None]+3)])
```

But it shows IndexError: too many indices for array

As for `a<i[:,None,None]+3`

it correctly shows

```
array([[[ True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

But when I use `b[np.where(a<i[:,None,None]+3)]`, it again shows IndexError: too many indices for array. I cannot get the correct output of `c`.

Answer (score 1):

I am sensing you are trying to vectorize things here, though not explicitly mentioned. Now, I don't think you can index like that in a vectorized manner. To solve your qustion in a vectorized manner, I would suggest a more efficient way to get the sum-reduction with `matrix-multiplication` using [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) and with help from `broadcasting` as you had set out already in your trials.

Thus, one solution would be -

```
from __future__ import division

i = np.arange(3)
mask = a<i[:,None,None]+3
c = np.tensordot(b,mask,axes=((0,1),(1,2)))/mask.sum((1,2))
```

[Related post to understand `tensordot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/).

**Possible improvements on performance**

- Convert the mask to float dtype before feeding to `np.dot` as BLAS based matrix-multiplication would be faster with it.
- Use `np.count_nonzero` instead of `np.sum` for counting booleans. So, use it to replace `mask.sum()` part.

Comment: Do the sum or average is just an example, actually I just wanna get ' b[np.where(a<i[:,None,None]+3)] ' work, I think I need add new axis in b, but I don't know how.

Comment: @kinderchan If I understand correctly, you can use : np.broadcast_to(b, mask.shape)[mask]?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work, I also use b[mask,i[:,None]], it failed either.

Comment: @kinderchan You need to explain your "doesn't work" part better. I would suggest editing your question and tell us what you expect to get with something like : `b[np.where(a<i[:,None,None]+3)]`.

Comment: I re-editted the question, the problem is `np.where(a<i[:,None,None]+3)` gives 3d array, but `b` is 2d.

Comment: @kinderchan Let me repeat - Please edit the question and tell us the **output that you expect with : `b[np.where(a<i[:,None,None]+3)]`**. Also, see if `b*mask` gives you that.

Comment: I changed my question again. As for your way, I checked `np.sum(b*mask,(1,2))/mask.sum((1,2))` is faster than `np.tensordot(b,mask,axes=((0,1),(1,2)))/mask.sum((1,2))`, and converting bool to float also makes the algorithm faster. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @kinderchan Nah, you can't get your expected output with `np.where`. As for `tensordot` being slower, that's not possible, not at least with decent sized arrays or you are timing it wrongly.