# Numpy - multiple 3d array with a 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying the following:

Given a matrix A (x, y ,3) and another matrix B (3, 3), I would like to return a (x, y, 3) matrix in which the 3rd dimension of A is multiplied by the values of B (similar when an RGB image is transformed into gray, only that those "RGB" values are multiplied by a matrix and not scalars)...

Here's what I've tried:

```
np.multiply(B, A)
np.einsum('ijk,jl->ilk', B, A)
np.einsum('ijk,jl->ilk', A, B)
```

All of them failed with dimensions not aligned.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which axis of `B` is `sum-reduced`?

Comment: I'm trying to do B * A, where A's 3rd axis is changed

Comment: So, last axis of `B` is reduced?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
np.tensordot(A,B,axes=((2),(1)))
```

[Related post to understand `tensordot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/).

`einsum` equivalent would be -

```
np.einsum('ijk,lk->ijl', A, B)
```

We can also use `A.dot(B.T)`, but that would be looping under the hoods. So, might not be the most preferred one, but it's a compact solution,

Comment: I got no error with these functions! :)) but for some reason I get wrong values...I mean when I try to display the image with the new values I get an error

Comment: @DanielY Maybe you were meant to `sum-reduce` the first axis of `B`? Then, use : `np.tensordot(A,B,axes=((2),(0)))`?

Comment: @DanielY Also, make sure you are not overflowing and also using uint8 dtype for image displaying.

Comment: I get many negative values...I think my B is wrong or upside down...I'll check that. Thanks

Comment: When trying tensordot() function I get a result matrix of (3, x, y) instead of (x, y, 3)

Comment: @DanielY If `A` is `(x,y,3) and `B` is (3,3)`, with `np.tensordot(A,B,axes=((2),(1)))` you would have a result of shape `(x,y,3)`. So, check again.

Comment: Please remember i'm doing B*A and not A*B, so running np.tensordot(B,A,axes=((1),(2))) which is what you wrote only with B, A and their axes upside down, I get shape (3, x, y)

Comment: @DanielY And why would you be doing `np.tensordot(B,A,axes=((1),(2)))`, when I suggested something else? Why not try what I posted?

Comment: In matrix multiplication as far as I know, order counts. You suggested A * B while I want B * A

Comment: @DanielY Please read the linked - `Related post to understand tensordot`.

Comment: @DanielY Let me ask again - Have you tried : `np.tensordot(A,B,axes=((2),(1)))`?

Comment: Yes I did, the dimensions are right. I didn't got valid values though

Comment: @DanielY Can you add sample case alongwith expected values into the question?

Comment: I'm actually trying to implement RGB to YIQ transformation using numpy actions only, according to the matrix here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ , so I have no specific test-case, only that the values shouldn't exceed certain range

Comment: @DanielY Without sample that reproduces your issue, can't help really.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the confusion, I think you can do something like this, using simple numpy methods:

First you can reshape A in a way that its fibers (or depth vectors A[:,:,i]) will be placed as columns in matrix C:

```
C = A.reshape(x*y,3).T
```

Then using a simple matrix multiplication you can do:

```
D = numpy.dot(B,C)
```

Finally bring the result back to the original dimensions:

```
D.T.reshape([x,y,3])
```

Comment: I'm trying to do B * A, I've tried what you suggested and got operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (x, y, 3)

Comment: Just told you above, force B to have shape (3,3,1)!

Comment: Sorry, I meant error operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3, 1) (x, y, 3)

Comment: Ok, I think I got what you mean, but x or y must have dimension 3 isn't it?

Comment: nope...the 3rd dimension of A is 3, x and y can be any value

Comment: Your updated comment did get me the expected result, but so did @Divakar's answer, so thanks a lot but I got what I need :)