# numpy - matrix multiple 3x3 and 100x100x3 arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have the following:

```
import numpy as np

XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50 = np.asarray([
    [3.1338561, -1.6168667, -0.4906146],
    [-0.9787684, 1.9161415, 0.0334540],
    [0.0719453, -0.2289914, 1.4052427],
])

XYZ_1 = np.asarray([0.25, 0.4, 0.1])
XYZ_2 = np.random.rand(100,100,3)

np.matmul(XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50, XYZ_1) # valid operation
np.matmul(XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50, XYZ_2) # makes no sense mathematically
```

How do I perform the same operation on XYZ_2 that I would on XYZ_2?  Do I somehow reshape the array first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to `sum-reduce` the last axis of `XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50` `(axis=1)` with the last one of `XYZ_2` `(axis=2)`. So, you can use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) like so -

```
np.tensordot(XYZ_2, XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50, axes=((2),(1)))
```

[Related post to understand `tensordot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/).

---

For completeness, we can surely use `np.matmul` too after swappping last two axes of `XYZ_2`, like so -

```
np.matmul(XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50, XYZ_2.swapaxes(1,2)).swapaxes(1,2)
```

This won't be as efficient as `tensordot` one.

---

Runtime test -

```
In [158]: XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50 = np.asarray([
     ...:     [3.1338561, -1.6168667, -0.4906146],
     ...:     [-0.9787684, 1.9161415, 0.0334540],
     ...:     [0.0719453, -0.2289914, 1.4052427],
     ...: ])
     ...: 
     ...: XYZ_1 = np.asarray([0.25, 0.4, 0.1])
     ...: XYZ_2 = np.random.rand(100,100,3)

# @Julien's soln
In [159]: %timeit XYZ_2.dot(XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50.T)
1000 loops, best of 3: 450 µs per loop

In [160]: %timeit np.tensordot(XYZ_2, XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50, axes=((2),(1)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.1 µs per loop
```

Generally speaking, when it comes to `sum-reductions` on tensors, `tensordot` is much more efficient. Since, the axis of `sum-reduction` is just one, we can make the tensor a `2D` array by reshaping, use `np.dot`, get the result and reshape back to `3D`.

Comment: Thank you -- this answer is excellent.  It's interesting that tensordot beats regular dot with transpose here, speed-wise.

Comment: @BrandonDube My understanding is that for tensors, `dot` is looping at some level (most probably at C level), while `tensordot` avoids it.

Comment: Wow! Didn't know that! Any insight as to why changing the shape gives 10x faster? That doesn't seem to make any sense...

Comment: @Julien You mean why the dot with reshape step : `XYZ_2.reshape(-1,3)...` is faster than `XYZ_2.dot(XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50.T)`? Because, with the reshaped 2D version, there's no looping for `np.dot`.

Comment: but the cost of looping through the shape should be totally negligible compared to the actual computations right? At the end of the day 2 nested for loops of 100 should be the same as 1 long 10,000 for loop, no?

Comment: @Julien `np.dot` leverages BLAS instead of actual looping. So, for this case, without reshape, it makes 100 BLAS calls, whereas with 2D reshaped version just one BLAS call. `tensordot` probably reshapes to `2D` (probably at C level)
 and then leverages one BLAS call.The slowness comes with the 100 BLAS calls, that's my understanding.

Comment: @Divakar -- I looked at this again this morning and made an edit to your answer -- tensordot scrambles the axes, but you can swap them around for free.

Comment: @BrandonDube Which axes are to be swapped?

Comment: @Divakar -- see my proposed edit -- the output is of shape (3,100,100), the output needs to have its axes circshifted.

Comment: @BrandonDube We were just needed to swap the positions of inputs there. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You probably simply want this:

```
XYZ_2.dot(XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50.T)
```

`np.matmul(XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50, XYZ_1)` is equivalent to `XYZ_1.dot(XYZ_to_sRGB_mat_D50.T)`, you can then simply broadcast the operation to a 100 x 100 x 3 matrix.