# How to avoid Kronecker product in NumPy computations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, matrix-multiplication

### **Background**

After generating a list of random weights:

```
sizes = [784,30,10]
weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1],sizes[1:])]
```

utilize Numpy's Kronecker product to create `foo` (with shape `(900, 23520)`):

```
foo = np.kron(np.identity(30),weights[0])
```

Then, matrix multiply `foo` with a slice from `data`, namely,

```
bar = np.dot(foo,data[0])
```

whereby the `data[0].shape` is `(23520,)` and `data[0].dtype` is `float32`.

### **Question**

`foo` is rather wasteful. How can `weights[0]`, which has shape `(30,784)`, be utilized for the multiplication with `data[0]` in a more resourceful manner?

More generally, `data[0]` is a slice from an array with shape `(1666,23520)`, so the multiplication procedure will need to be carried out 1666 times. Also, the data array is close to sparse with less than 20% of entries being non-zero.

Here's the loop I had tried:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    foo = np.kron(np.identity(30),weights[0])
    bar = np.dot(foo,data[i])
```

Comment: And you need to do this for all rows - `data[1]`, `data[2]` .. `data[1665]`? By sparse, do you mean the type is sparse matrix?

Comment: @Divakar yeah. I tried it with a for loop and the computation took far too long. Yes, the data matrix is sparse. Mostly entries 0.

Comment: Could you add that loopy code for completeness?

Comment: @Divakar entered.

Comment: How sparse are your data?

Comment: @PaulPanzer good question. Less than 20% of entries are non-zero.

Comment: That's borderline. You'd have to test whether using a sparse matrix for `data` would make things faster. The good news is it's easy. And in any case it will save you some memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to reshape `data` into `3D` tensor and then use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) against `weights[0]` and thus by-pass `foo` creation, like so -

```
k = 30 # kernel size
data3D = data.reshape(data.shape[0],k,-1)
out = np.tensordot(data3D, weights[0], axes=(2,1)).reshape(-1,k**2)
```

Under the hoods, `tensordot` uses transposing axes, reshaping and then `np.dot`. So, using all that *manual-labor* to avoid the function call to `tensordot`, we would have one, like so -

```
out = data.reshape(-1,data.shape[1]//k).dot(weights[0].T).reshape(-1,k**2)
```

[Related post to understand `tensordot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/).

**Sample run**

Let's use a toy example to explain on what's going on to people who might not have understand the problem :

```
In [68]: # Toy setup and code run with original codes
    ...: k = 3 # kernel size, which is 30 in the original case
    ...: 
    ...: data = np.random.rand(4,6)
    ...: w0 = np.random.rand(3,2) # this is weights[0]
    ...: foo = np.kron(np.identity(k), w0)
    ...: output_first_row = foo.dot(data[0])
```

So, the question is to get rid of the `foo` creation step and get to `output_first_row` and do this for all rows of `data`.

The proposed solution is :

```
...: data3D = data.reshape(data.shape[0],k,-1)
...: vectorized_out = np.tensordot(data3D, w0, axes=(2,1)).reshape(-1,k**2)
```

Let's verify the results :

```
In [69]: output_first_row
Out[69]: array([ 0.11,  0.13,  0.34,  0.67,  0.53,  1.51,  0.17,  0.16,  0.44])

In [70]: vectorized_out
Out[70]: 
array([[ 0.11,  0.13,  0.34,  0.67,  0.53,  1.51,  0.17,  0.16,  0.44],
       [ 0.43,  0.23,  0.73,  0.43,  0.38,  1.05,  0.64,  0.49,  1.41],
       [ 0.57,  0.45,  1.3 ,  0.68,  0.51,  1.48,  0.45,  0.28,  0.85],
       [ 0.41,  0.35,  0.98,  0.4 ,  0.24,  0.75,  0.22,  0.28,  0.71]])
```

**Runtime test for all proposed approaches -**

```
In [30]: import numpy as np

In [31]: sizes = [784,30,10]

In [32]: weights = [np.random.rand(y, x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1],sizes[1:])]

In [33]: data = np.random.rand(1666,23520)

In [37]: k = 30 # kernel size

# @Paul Panzer's soln
In [38]: %timeit (weights[0] @ data.reshape(-1, 30, 784).swapaxes(1, 2)).swapaxes(1, 2)
1 loops, best of 3: 707 ms per loop

In [39]: %timeit np.tensordot(data.reshape(data.shape[0],k,-1), weights[0], axes=(2,1)).reshape(-1,k**2)
10 loops, best of 3: 114 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit data.reshape(-1,data.shape[1]//k).dot(weights[0].T).reshape(-1,k**2)
10 loops, best of 3: 118 ms per loop
```

[`This Q&A`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646944/3293881) and the comments under, might help understand how `tensordot` works better with `tensors`.

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially doing matrix-matrix multiplication where the first factor is `weights[0]` and the second is `data[i]` chopped up into 30 equal slices that form the columns.

```
import numpy as np

sizes = [784,30,10]
weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1],sizes[1:])]

k = 2
# create sparse data
data = np.maximum(np.random.uniform(-100, 1, (k, 23520)), 0)

foo = np.kron(np.identity(30),weights[0])

# This is the original loop as a list comprehension
bar = [np.dot(foo,d) for d in data]

# This is the equivalent using matrix multiplication.
# We can take advantage of the fact that the '@' operator
# can do batch matrix multiplication (it uses the last two
# dimensions as the matrix and all others as batch index).
# The reshape does the chopping up but gives us rows where columns
# are required, hence the first swapaxes.
# The second swapaxes is to make the result directly comparable to
# the `np.kron` based result.
bar2 = (weights[0] @ data.reshape(k, 30, 784).swapaxes(1, 2)).swapaxes(1, 2)

# Instead of letting numpy do the batching we can glue all the
# columns of all the second factors together into one matrix   
bar3 = (weights[0] @ data.reshape(-1, 784).T).T.reshape(k, -1)

# This last formulation works more or less unchanged on sparse data
from scipy import sparse
dsp = sparse.csr_matrix(data.reshape(-1, 784))
bar4 = (weights[0] @ dsp.T).T.reshape(k, -1)


print(np.allclose(bar, bar2.reshape(k, -1)))
print(np.allclose(bar, bar3))
print(np.allclose(bar, bar4))
```

Prints:

```
True
True
True
```