# How can I take a dot product along a particular dimension in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra, numpy-ndarray

I have two arrays. One is `n` by `p` and the other is `d` by `p` by `r`. I would like my output to be `d` by `n` by `r`, which I can achieve easily as I construct the tensor `B` below. However, I would like to do this without that loop.

```
import numpy

X = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7],[7,8,9]]) # n x p
betas = numpy.array([[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]], [[5,6],[5,6],[5,6]]]) # d x p x r

print X.shape
print betas.shape

B = numpy.zeros((betas.shape[0],X.shape[0],betas.shape[2]))
print B.shape

for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    B[i,:,:] = numpy.dot(X, betas[i])

print "B",B

C = numpy.tensordot(X, betas, axes=([1],[0]))
print C.shape
```

I have tried in various ways to get `C` to match `B`, but so far I have been unsuccessful. Is there a way that does not involve a call to `reshape`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) and then need to permutes axes -

```
B = np.tensordot(betas, X, axes=(1,1)).swapaxes(1,2)
# Or np.tensordot(X, betas, axes=(1,1)).swapaxes(0,1)
```

[Related post to understand `tensordot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/).

Comment: And it returns a view, rather than a new array! Wonderful.

Comment: For larger arrays, `tensordot` is superfast.. but for small arrays `np.dot` is 4x faster than `tensordot`.. not sure why this is the case

Comment: @kmario23 See here for a related discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646944/

Answer (score 4):

Since the `dot` rule is 'last of A with 2nd to the last of B', you can do `X.dot(betas)` and get a (n,d,r) array (this sums on the shared `p` dimension).  Then you just need a transpose to get (d,n,r)

```
In [200]: X.dot(betas).transpose(1,0,2)
Out[200]: 
array([[[  6,  12],
        [ 12,  24],
        [ 18,  36],
        [ 24,  48]],

       [[ 30,  36],
        [ 60,  72],
        [ 90, 108],
        [120, 144]]])
```

We can also write the `einsum` version directly from the dimensions specification:

```
np.einsum('np,dpr->dnr', X,betas)
```

So does `matmul` (this does `dot` on the last 2 axes, while `d` comes along for the ride).

```
X@betas
```

> - If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of
>     matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.

Comment: See my timings.. `np.dot` is faster for small arrays than `tensordot` but it's the other way around for larger arrays. Not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: Tensordot uses `dot`, just massaging inputs and results to fit (reshape and transpose).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using **[`numpy.dot()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)**, which also **returns a view** as you requested, and most importantly more than **4x faster than [tensordot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html)** approach, particularly for small sized arrays. But, [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) is way faster than plain [`np.dot()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for reasonably larger arrays. See timings below.

```
In [108]: X.shape
Out[108]: (4, 3)

In [109]: betas.shape
Out[109]: (2, 3, 2)

# use `np.dot` and roll the second axis to first position
In [110]: dot_prod = np.rollaxis(np.dot(X, betas), 1)

In [111]: dot_prod.shape
Out[111]: (2, 4, 2)

# @Divakar's approach
In [113]: B = np.tensordot(betas, X, axes=(1,1)).swapaxes(1,2)

# sanity check :)
In [115]: np.all(np.equal(dot_prod, B))
Out[115]: True
```

---

Now, the performance of both approaches:

- For small sized arrays [`np.dot()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) is 4x faster than [`np.tensordot()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html)

---

```
# @Divakar's approach
In [117]: %timeit B = np.tensordot(betas, X, axes=(1,1)).swapaxes(1,2)
10.6 µs ± 2.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# @hpaulj's approach
In [151]: %timeit esum_dot = np.einsum('np, dpr -> dnr', X, betas)
4.16 µs ± 235 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# proposed approach: more than 4x faster!!
In [118]: %timeit dot_prod = np.rollaxis(np.dot(X, betas), 1)
2.47 µs ± 11.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

- For reasonably larger arrays, [`np.tensordot()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) is much faster than [`np.dot()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)

---

```
In [129]: X = np.random.randint(1, 10, (600, 500))
In [130]: betas = np.random.randint(1, 7, (300, 500, 300))

In [131]: %timeit B = np.tensordot(betas, X, axes=(1,1)).swapaxes(1,2)
18.2 s ± 2.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [132]: %timeit dot_prod = np.rollaxis(np.dot(X, betas), 1)
52.8 s ± 14.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Once, you get past the initial setup overhead with `tensordot`, it should be faster than `np.dot` version - `np.rollaxis(np.dot(X, betas), 1)`. So, it doesn't have to be `reasonably larger arrays`.

Comment: @Divakar I see. So, hpaulj contends that `np.tensordot` uses `np.dot`. I think I'll have to go over the code to get a good grasp of what's happening... I really hope that NumPy devs start implementing support for GPUs well early.. :)