# Compute weighted sum of 3D and 2D NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a 2D NumPy array A of shape (n, 3) and a 3D array B of shape (x, y, n). I want to create a 3D array Y of shape (x, y, 3) - which is an RGB image.

The 3rd dimension of B contains probabilities [0, 1] which sum up to 1. Array A is a list of RGB colors (one color for each probability). 
For each element C in the 3rd dimension of B I want to compute the sum of A * C so that I get a RGB color vector.

**Example**:

Given a colormap A as

```
A = [(255   0   0),
     (  0 255   0),
     (  0   0 255)]
```

and an element C in the 3rd dimension of B at point (x, y) as

```
C = [0.2, 0.6, 0.20]
```

I want to compute `C' = sum(A * C)` as

```
  (255   0   0) * 0.2
+ (  0 255   0) * 0.6
+ (  0   0 255) * 0.2
---------------------
  ( 51 153  51)
```

and assign

```
Y[x, y, :] = C'
```

I know I could just iterate over x and y with a for loop and compute each element at a time but I wonder if this can be done in a vectorized manner that I don't have to iterate over the array myself (mainly for performance reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are `sum-reducing` the first axis from `A` against the third from `B`, while the rest of the axes are *spread out*. This is a perfect setup to leverage BLAS based matrix-multiplication for tensors - [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html), like so -

```
C = np.tensordot(B,A,axes=((2),(0)))
```

[Related post to understand `tensordot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/).

We can also *manually* reshape to `2D` and use the matrix-multiplication for `2D` : `np.dot`, like so -

```
B.reshape(-1,n).dot(A).reshape(x,y,3)
```

Note that `B.dot(A)` works as well, but that would be slower, most probably as it would loop through the first axis of `B`, while performing `2D` matrix-multiplications for each 2D slice off it against `A`.

Runtime test -

```
In [180]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: x,y,n = 100,100,100
     ...: A = np.random.rand(n,3)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(x,y,n)

# @Crazy Ivan's soln
In [181]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,kli->klj', A, B)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.21 ms per loop

In [182]: %timeit np.tensordot(B,A,axes=((2),(0)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 ms per loop

In [183]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: x,y,n = 200,200,200
     ...: A = np.random.rand(n,3)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(x,y,n)

# @Crazy Ivan's soln
In [184]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,kli->klj', A, B)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.2 ms per loop

In [185]: %timeit np.tensordot(B,A,axes=((2),(0)))
100 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm accepting this as answer because it proposes the faster solution.

Answer (score 2):

The method [`numpy.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) is convenient for this:

```
np.einsum('ij,kli->klj', A, B)
```

The notation says: multiply `A[i, j]` by `B[k, l, i]` and sum over `i`; place the result in the cell `[k, l, j]`.

Example:

```
A = np.array([(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)])
B = np.array([[[0.2, 0.6, 0.20], [0.2, 0.2, 0.60]], [[0.4, 0.4, 0.2], [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]]])
Y = np.einsum('ij,kli->klj', A, B)
```

Then `Y` is

```
array([[[  51. ,  153. ,   51. ],
        [  51. ,   51. ,  153. ]],

       [[ 102. ,  102. ,   51. ],
        [  76.5,   76.5,  102. ]]])
```