# Tensordot for vectors in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensordot

I'm currently trying to create a tensordot using numpy for vectors. For example, let's say I have the following variables:

```
a = [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3,4])] 
b = [np.array([5,6]), np.array([7,8])]
```

and I want to compute the "tensor product of the vectors", i.e. [a[0]*b[0], a[0]*b[1], a[1]*b[0], a[1]*b[1]] which would give in our example:

```
a x b = [[5,12], [7,16], [15, 24], [21, 32]]
```

I've tried many combinations using tensordot along different axes, but it never gives me the results I want :((

For example, I tried the followings:

```
np.tensordot(a,b)
```

which gives me `array(70)`

or `np.tensordot(a,b, axes = 0)`
which gives me

```
array([[[[ 5,  6],
     [ 7,  8]],

    [[10, 12],
     [14, 16]]],


   [[[15, 18],
     [21, 24]],

    [[20, 24],
     [28, 32]]]])
```

I also tried using different axes such as `np.tensordot(a,b, axes = ([0], [1]))` with no success...

Can someone please help me? :)
I'm sure it's pretty trivial but I seem to miss something

Thanks.

Comment: Show us a few of those `tensordot` applications, and what is wrong.

Comment: I tried to explain the `tensordot` results.  But what makes you think that `tensordot` should give you the desired result?

Comment: Another way to put my question - what's `a tensordot`?  I am aware of this `numpy` function.  But it sounds like you are trying to produce a product that is defined elsewhere (math theory?).  If so, where?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer below, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: As for my aim, I'm defining f and g two functions with images in the tensor space by their values at all x, i.e. [f(x_1), f(x_2), ..., f(x_n)] with x_1, ..., x_n being the finite set of definitions of f and g.
The product I'm defining can be then seen as the flattened vector of values of the function h defined as the tensor product of the function f x g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [663]: a = np.array([[1, 2], [3,4]]); b = np.array([[5,6], [7,8]])
```

A simple dot (matrix product) of these 2 arrays:

```
In [664]: a.dot(b)
Out[664]: 
array([[19, 22],
       [43, 50]])
```

Your desired array:

```
In [665]: [a[0]*b[0], a[0]*b[1], a[1]*b[0], a[1]*b[1]] 
Out[665]: [array([ 5, 12]), array([ 7, 16]), array([15, 24]), array([21, 32])]
In [666]: np.array(_)
Out[666]: 
array([[ 5, 12],
       [ 7, 16],
       [15, 24],
       [21, 32]])
```

`np.tensordot` is an attempt to generalize `np.dot`; for 2d arrays like this it can't do anything that a few added transposes can't.

Your result isn't a `tensordot` in that sense.  `dot` involves `sum of products`; you aren't doing any sums.  Rather it looks more like an outer product, or may a variation on `kron`.

With a couple trials I reproduced your array with `einsum`:

```
In [673]: np.einsum('ij,kj->ikj',a,b)
Out[673]: 
array([[[ 5, 12],
        [ 7, 16]],

       [[15, 24],
        [21, 32]]])
In [674]: _.reshape(-1,2)
Out[674]: 
array([[ 5, 12],
       [ 7, 16],
       [15, 24],
       [21, 32]])
```

`einsum` like `dot` and `tensordot` is built around sums of products, but gives us a finer control over which axes are multiplied, and which are summed.  Here, we don't sum any.

I can get the same 3d array with:

```
In [675]: a[:,None,:]*b[None,:,:]
Out[675]: 
array([[[ 5, 12],
        [ 7, 16]],

       [[15, 24],
        [21, 32]]])
```

### tensordot

According to the docs, the default value for axes is 2:

```
In [714]: np.tensordot(a,b)
Out[714]: array(70)
In [715]: np.tensordot(a,b,axes=2)
Out[715]: array(70)
```

> - `axes = 2` : (default) tensor double contraction :math:`a:b`

In other words, multiply the arrays, and sum over all axes.  This is clearer, in my mind, with `einsum` notation:

```
In [719]: np.einsum('ij,ij',a,b)
Out[719]: 70


In [718]: np.tensordot(a,b,axes=0).shape
Out[718]: (2, 2, 2, 2)
```

> - `axes = 0` : tensor product :math:`a\\otimes b`
>     : tensor product a\otimes b

```
np.einsum('ij,kl',a,b)
```

I can see your desired result, or at least the `Out[673]` version in your (2,2,2,2) array, as some sort of diagonal subset.

I don't use these scalar like `axes` modes of `tensordot` much.  In a previous post or two I've puzzled over them, but I don't have a good feel. I much prefer the clarity if `einsum`.

[How does numpy.tensordot function works step-by-step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989572/how-does-numpy-tensordot-function-works-step-by-step)