# Algorithm for tensordot implemented in numba is much slower than numpy's

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to expand the numpy "tensordot" such that things like:
`K_ijklm = A_ki * B_jml` can be written in a clear way like this: `K = mytensordot(A,B,[2,0],[1,4,3])`

To my understanding, numpy's tensordot (with optional argument 0) would be able to do something like this: `K_kijml = A_ki * B_jml`, i.e. keeping the order of the indexes. Therefore I would then have to do a number of `np.swapaxes()` to obtain the matrix `K_ijklm', which in a complicated case can be an easy source of errors (potentially very hard to debug).

The problem is that my implementation is slow (10x slower than tensordot [EDIT: It is actually MUCH slower than that]), even when using numba. I was wondering if anyone would have some insight on what could be done to improve the performance of my algorithm.

### MWE

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import itertools
import timeit

@nb.jit()
def myproduct(dimN):
    N=np.prod(dimN)
    L=len(dimN)
    Product=np.zeros((N,L),dtype=np.int32)
    rn=0
    for n in range(1,N):
        for l in range(L):
            if l==0:
                rn=1
            v=Product[n-1,L-1-l]+rn
            rn = 0
            if v == dimN[L-1-l]:
                v = 0
                rn = 1
            Product[n,L-1-l]=v
    return Product

@nb.jit()
def mytensordot(A,B,iA,iB):
    iA,iB = np.array(iA,dtype=np.int32),np.array(iB,dtype=np.int32)
    dimA,dimB = A.shape,B.shape
    NdimA,NdimB=len(dimA),len(dimB)

    if len(iA) != NdimA: raise ValueError("iA must be same size as dim A")
    if len(iB) != NdimB: raise ValueError("iB must be same size as dim B")

    NdimN = NdimA + NdimB
    dimN=np.zeros(NdimN,dtype=np.int32)
    dimN[iA]=dimA
    dimN[iB]=dimB
    Out=np.zeros(dimN)
    indexes = myproduct(dimN)

    for nidxs in indexes:
        idxA = tuple(nidxs[iA])
        idxB = tuple(nidxs[iB])
        v=A[(idxA)]*B[(idxB)]
        Out[tuple(nidxs)]=v
    return Out



A=np.random.random((4,5,3))
B=np.random.random((6,4))

def runmytdot():
    return mytensordot(A,B,[0,2,3],[1,4])
def runtensdot():
    return np.tensordot(A,B,0).swapaxes(1,3).swapaxes(2,3)


print(np.all(runmytdot()==runtensdot()))
print(timeit.timeit(runmytdot,number=100))
print(timeit.timeit(runtensdot,number=100))
```

### Result:

```
True
1.4962144780438393
0.003484356915578246
```

Comment: @senderle Actually, since I do the first evaluation of the functions before the timing code, the compilation time is not in the timed result. I change the example to use larger dimensions matrices and my code is embarrassingly slow :(

Comment: OK, I had a moment to test this the proper way, using `setup`, and it gave similar results, so these numbers seem legit.

Comment: Still not sure what the issue is but see [this](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#what-is-nopython-mode). You get better debugging information if you pass `nopython=True`. If you do, it won't compile anything it can't optimize. Otherwise it will automatically fall back to "object mode," meaning it goes at pure Python speed.

Comment: `np.tensordot` is a front end to `np.dot`, the main sum-of-products function.  It swaps axes and reshapes the inputs to reduce the problem to a simple 2d matrix product call.  What you describe looks more like a generalized outer product, combining a 3d and 2d to produce a 5d.  There's no summation along a shared dimension.

Comment: I should amend that last comment.  The original intent of `tensordot` was to generalize `np.dot`.  `tensordot` with `axes=0` does do the outer product.  I explore its action in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989572/how-does-numpy-tensordot-function-works-step-by-step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tensordot` with scalar axes values can be obscure.  I explored it in

[How does numpy.tensordot function works step-by-step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989572/how-does-numpy-tensordot-function-works-step-by-step)

There I deduced that `np.tensordot(A, B, axes=0)` is equivalent using `axes=[[], []]`.

```
In [757]: A=np.random.random((4,5,3))
     ...: B=np.random.random((6,4))

In [758]: np.tensordot(A,B,0).shape
Out[758]: (4, 5, 3, 6, 4)
In [759]: np.tensordot(A,B,[[],[]]).shape
Out[759]: (4, 5, 3, 6, 4)
```

That in turn is equivalent to calling `dot` with a new size 1 sum-of-products dimenson:

```
In [762]: np.dot(A[...,None],B[...,None,:]).shape
Out[762]: (4, 5, 3, 6, 4)

(4,5,3,1) * (6,1,4)   # the 1 is the last of A and 2nd to the last of B
```

`dot` is fast, using BLAS (or equivalent) code.  Swapping axes and reshaping is also relatively fast.

`einsum` gives us a lot of control over axes

replicating the above products:

```
In [768]: np.einsum('jml,ki->jmlki',A,B).shape
Out[768]: (4, 5, 3, 6, 4)
```

and with  swapping:

```
In [769]: np.einsum('jml,ki->ijklm',A,B).shape
Out[769]: (4, 4, 6, 3, 5)
```

---

A minor point - the double swap can be written as one transpose:

```
.swapaxes(1,3).swapaxes(2,3)
.transpose(0,3,1,2,4)
```

Comment: einsum did the trick! for my example it should read `np.einsum("ikl,jm->ijklm",A,B)`. It is also the fastest method

Comment: Yeah, `einsum` makes sense for this -- I probably should have thought of that. I was more interested in getting the jit to work... which I did! @hpaulj's answer should be the accepted one, but hopefully [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54635558/577088) will help someone else having similar problems with `numba`.

Answer (score 4):

You have run into [a known issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2771). `numpy.zeros` [requires a tuple](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) when creating a multidimensional array. If you pass something other than a tuple, it sometimes works, but that's only because `numpy` is smart about converting the object into a tuple first.

The trouble is that `numba` does not currently support [conversion of arbitrary iterables into tuples](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2771#issuecomment-368310863). So this line fails when you try to compile it in `nopython=True` mode. (A couple of others fail too, but this is the first.)

```
Out=np.zeros(dimN)
```

In theory you could call `np.prod(dimN)`, create a flat array of zeros, and reshape it, but then you run into the very same problem: the `reshape` method of `numpy` arrays requires a tuple!

This is quite a vexing problem with `numba` -- I had not encountered it before. I really doubt the solution I have found is the correct one, but it is a working solution that allows us to compile a version in `nopython=True` mode.

The core idea is to avoid using tuples for indexing by directly implementing an indexer that follows the `strides` of the array:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def index_arr(a, ix_arr):
    strides = np.array(a.strides) / a.itemsize
    ix = int((ix_arr * strides).sum())
    return a.ravel()[ix]

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def index_set_arr(a, ix_arr, val):
    strides = np.array(a.strides) / a.itemsize
    ix = int((ix_arr * strides).sum())
    a.ravel()[ix] = val
```

This allows us to get and set values without needing a tuple.

We can also avoid using `reshape` by passing the output buffer into the jitted function, and wrapping that function in a helper:

```
@nb.jit()  # We can't use nopython mode here...
def mytensordot(A, B, iA, iB):
    iA, iB = np.array(iA, dtype=np.int32), np.array(iB, dtype=np.int32)
    dimA, dimB = A.shape, B.shape
    NdimA, NdimB = len(dimA), len(dimB)

    if len(iA) != NdimA:
        raise ValueError("iA must be same size as dim A")
    if len(iB) != NdimB:
        raise ValueError("iB must be same size as dim B")

    NdimN = NdimA + NdimB
    dimN = np.zeros(NdimN, dtype=np.int32)
    dimN[iA] = dimA
    dimN[iB] = dimB
    Out = np.zeros(dimN)
    return mytensordot_jit(A, B, iA, iB, dimN, Out)
```

Since the helper contains no loops, it adds some overhead, but the overhead is pretty trivial. Here's the final jitted function:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def mytensordot_jit(A, B, iA, iB, dimN, Out):
    for i in range(np.prod(dimN)):
        nidxs = int_to_idx(i, dimN)
        a = index_arr(A, nidxs[iA])
        b = index_arr(B, nidxs[iB])
        index_set_arr(Out, nidxs, a * b)
    return Out
```

Unfortunately, this does not wind up generating as much of a speedup as we might like. On smaller arrays it's about 5x slower than `tensordot`; on larger arrays it's still 50x slower. (But at least it's not 1000x slower!) This is not too surprising in retrospect, since `dot` and `tensordot` are both using BLAS under the hood, as @hpaulj [reminds us](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54636977/577088).

After finishing this code, I saw that `einsum` has solved your real problem -- nice!

But the underlying issue that your original question points to -- that indexing with arbitrary-length tuples is not possible in jitted code -- is still a frustration. So hopefully this will be useful to someone else!

Comment: Thank you, this means that also the loop is broken since it also contains conversion to tuples... I'm guessing that my answer is still probably slower, even if jit was functioning optimally.

Comment: Well, slower maybe, but way, way faster than it is now. If I'm reading the code right, this is probably killing you right now: `for nidxs in indexes:` -- jitting that will really help...