# Is there a function for calculating all the pairwise dot products of the columns of a matrix, or between all pairs in a list of vectors?

Tags: python, numpy

Say you have n. vectors of arbitrary (but equal) length m each. Is there a (numpy?) function, or a quick way, of calculating all pairwise dot products between these n. vectors?

My initial thought was that you could calculate A<sup>T</sup>A and take the upper triangular portion, but I'm not sure if that matrix multiplication is slow/computationally intensive. Is there a quicker/efficient way? Or should I just define a function using a for loop for all combinations of pairs?

Comment: Do you mean scalar products ?

Comment: I you want to multiply all the columns of your 2-D array `arr` by all the other columns, use [tensordot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) : `np.tensordot(arr, arr, axes=(0,0))`. Result shape is `(n,n)`

Comment: @Chgad Yes, the dot product or scalar product or inner product.

Comment: @Brenlla Tensordot looks exactly what I need, thank you!

Comment: For more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41870228/6091318)

Comment: BTW, `A.T.dot(A)` should also work fine, no need to take triangular portions

Answer (score 1):

As per @Brenila’s comment, use [tensordot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html):

```
np.tensordot(arr, arr, axes=(0,0))
```

Result shape is `(n, n)` for `n = arr.shape[-1]`