# convolve a higher dimensional cube with a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am convolving a 3D datacube of the shape [nLambda,nX,nY] with a filter of the shape [nLambda,3]. I managed to get this to work for this situation, but I need to repeat this process on a large amount of cubes that are saved as [nt,nLambda,nX,nY]. I want to extend the code that I have to cope with that, but I keep messing up the tiling. Does anyone know how to do this?

My current program does:

```
datacube.shape         = [21,100,100]
filters.shape          = [21,3]
data_collapsed.shape   = [100,100,3]
```

I want it to do

```
datacube.shape         = [10,21,100,100]
filters.shape          = [21,3]
data_collapsed.shape   = [10,100,100,3]
```

The code that I use for 3D cubes

```
nl,nx,ny = datacube.shape
filter_rgb = np.tile(filters, (ny,nx,1,1))
filter_rgb = np.swapaxes(filter_rgb, 0,2)
data_rgb = np.tile(datacube,(3,1,1,1))
data_rgb = np.swapaxes(data_rgb,0,-1)
data_filtered = data_rgb * filter_rgb
data_collapsed = np.sum(data_filtered, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html).

For `datacube` as `4D` case -

```
data_collapsed = np.tensordot(datacube,filters,axes=(1,0))
```

For `3D` case -

```
data_collapsed = np.tensordot(datacube,filters,axes=(0,0))
```

[Related post to understand `tensordot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/).

Comment: oh wow that works! What would be the axes for the 3D example?

Comment: @Coolcrab Edited for both cases.