# Contraction along the last axe in numpy tensordot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am not very familiar with tensor algebra and I am having trouble understanding how to make `numpy.tensordot` do what I want.

The example I am working with is simple: given a tensor `a` with shape `(2,2,3)` and another `b` with shape `(2,1,3)`, I want a result tensor `c` with shape `(2,1)`. This tensor would be the result of the following, equivalent python code:

```py
n = a.shape[2]
c = np.zeros((2,n))
for k in range(n):
    c += a[:,:,k]*b[:,:,k]
```

The documentation says that the optional parameter `axes`:

> If an int N, sum over the last N axes of a and the first N axes of b in order. The sizes of the corresponding axes must match.

But I don't understand which "axes" are needed here (furthermore, when axes is a tuple or a tuple of tuples it gets even more confusing). Examples aren't very clear to me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way [`tensordot` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41871402/), it won't work here (not at least directly) because of the alignment requirement along the first axes. You can use `np.einsum` though to solve your case -

```
c = np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ij',a,b)
```

Alternatively, use `np.matmul`/`@-operator` (Python 3.x) -

```
np.matmul(a,b.swapaxes(1,2))[...,0] # or (a @ b.swapaxes(1,2))[...,0]
```

Comment: Just to be sure, if the b matrix changed to `(2,3)`, then `c = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',a,b)` would still do the same? (in which case I could just squash axes with dim = 1)

Comment: @Adrian Yup, should be the same.