# Calculate the dot product of an array of matrices and the rows or columns of another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, tensor, dot-product

Having two ndarrays, array `d` with shape (3,10,10) and array `e` with shape (3,10), how do I calculate the dot product of the first 10x10 matrix of `d` and the first row of `e`, the second 10x10 matrix of `d` and the second row of `e`, etc.

For example, having the following two arrays:

```
d = np.array([np.diag([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]), 
              np.diag([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]), 
              np.diag([3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3])])     
e = np.arange(30).reshape((3,10))
```

How do I calculate the 3x10 array:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38],
       [60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87]])
```

I tried using `np.dot` and `np.tensordot` and also transposing and adding a new axis to `e` before doing so, but I coulnd't figure out how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ij->ik',d,e)
```

Play around with its `optimize` flag to use BLAS.

Or `np.matmul` -

```
np.matmul(d,e[...,None])[...,0]
```

Note : On Python 3.x `np.matmul` could be replaced by `@ operator`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how this could possibly work using `np.tensordot`? I couldn't figure what my mistake was or if this even works using that function.

Comment: @AlexR `tensordot` won't work because we need to keep the first axis off them aligned. Read here for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/.