# Python tensor matrix multiply

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra, tensor

I have the tensor

```
A = 
[[[a,b],
  [c,d]],
 [[e,f],
  [g,h]]]
```

and the matrix

```
B = 
[[1,2],
 [3,4]]
```

I need to get

```
C = 
[[a*1+e*2,b*1+f*2],
 [c*3+g*4,d*3+h*4]]
```

How can I do this using numpy in matrix form? I've looked into `np.tensordot()` but it doesn't seem to help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1,9).reshape(2,2,2)
>>> a
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
>>> b = np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2)
>>> b
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> (a * b[None,:,:].T).sum(axis = 0)
array([[11, 14],
       [37, 44]])
```

Intermediate steps look like this:

```
>>> b[None,:,:]
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
>>> b[None,:,:].T
array([[[1],
        [3]],

       [[2],
        [4]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

OP's problem can be reformulated in a standard format using tensor notation and the so called [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)

*A <sub>k i j</sub>  B <sub>i k</sub>   ⇒   C <sub>i j</sub>*

Numpy has a convenient utility function to perform the kind of tensor operations that can be descibed using the Einstein summation convention, unsurprisingly named  [`numpy.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy-einsum), that allows to straightforwardly map the tensor notation to optimized C-level loops by the means of an *instruction string* that exactly reflects the tensor notation, `'kij, ik -> ij'`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)+1
b = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)+1
c = np.einsum('kij, ik -> ij', a, b)
print(c)
# [[11 14]
#  [37 44]]
```

---

*Merits of* `numpy.einsum`

1. The source code documents the details of the operation performed.
2. `np.einsum`typically is *fast*

   ```
   In [12]: import numpy as np 
       ...:  
       ...: i, j, k = 100, 320, 140 # just three largish numbers
       ...: a = np.random.random((k,i,j)) 
       ...: b = np.random.random((i,k))                                                      

   In [13]: %timeit np.einsum('kij,ik->ij', a, b)                                            
   7.47 ms ± 82.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

   In [14]: %timeit (a * b[None,:,:].T).sum(axis = 0)                                        
   49.3 ms ± 6.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
   ```