# Looping over np.einsum many times... Is there a faster way?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-einsum, log-likelihood

I have a likelihood function that I am trying to sample with MCMC. I have used no for loops in the log likelihood itself, but I do call `np.einsum()` once.

Here's a sample of what my current code looks like:

```
A = np.random.rand(4,50,60,200) # Random NDarray
B = np.random.rand(200,1000,4)  # Random NDarray
out = np.einsum('ijkl,lui->jkui', A, B, optimize="optimal")
```

The output `out` has dimensions (50,60,1000,4). This calculation is a bit too slow to allow for efficient MCMC sampling (~4 seconds on my machine), is there any way to speed it up? **One useful piece of information is that for each call of the log-likelihood function, while the actual values in the arrays A and B are changing, the dimensions of each array remains fixed.** I'd imagine this could be useful in speeding things up, since **the same elements are always being multiplied together.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well one of the axes stays aligned in `A` (first one) and `B` (last one) and stays in output as well (last one) and is a very small looping number of `4`. So, we could simply loop over that one with with [`np.tensordot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) for a tensor sum-reduction. The benefit of `4x` lesser memory congestion when working with such large datasets might overcome the 4x looping because the compute per iteration is also `4x` lesser.

Thus, a solution with `tensordot` would be -

```
def func1(A, B):
    out = np.empty(A.shape[1:3] + B.shape[1:])
    for i in range(len(A)):
        out[...,i] = np.tensordot(A[i], B[...,i],axes=(-1,0))
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [70]: A = np.random.rand(4,50,60,200) # Random NDarray
    ...: B = np.random.rand(200,1000,4)  # Random NDarray
    ...: out = np.einsum('ijkl,lui->jkui', A, B, optimize="optimal")

# Einsum solution without optimize    
In [71]: %timeit np.einsum('ijkl,lui->jkui', A, B)
2.89 s ± 109 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Einsum solution with optimize    
In [72]: %timeit np.einsum('ijkl,lui->jkui', A, B, optimize="optimal")
2.79 s ± 9.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)    

# @Paul Panzer's soln
In [74]: %timeit np.stack([np.tensordot(a,b,1) for a,b in zip(A,B.transpose(2,0,1))],-1)
183 ms ± 6.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [73]: %timeit func1(A,B)
158 ms ± 3.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Just to re-iterate the importance of memory-congestion and compute requirement, let's say we want to sum-reduce the last axis of length `4` as well, then we will see a noticeable difference in timings for `optimal` version -

```
In [78]: %timeit np.einsum('ijkl,lui->jkui', A, B, optimize="optimal")
2.76 s ± 9.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [79]: %timeit np.einsum('ijkl,lui->jku', A, B, optimize="optimal")
93.8 ms ± 3.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So, in that case, it would be better to go with `einsum`.

#### Specific to given problem

Given that dimensions of `A` and `B` stay the same, the array-initialization with `out = np.empty(A.shape[1:3] + B.shape[1:])` could be done as a one-time affair and loop through each call of the log-likelihood function with the proposed looping over to use `tensordot` and update output `out`.

Comment: @Jsn If you are new to `tensordot`, this could be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/ for some examples with it.

Comment: That memory-congestion insight is instructive. I wasn't aware that the effects are so drastic.

Comment: The memory-congestion example is more of an einsum vs BLAS issue. 78 will reorganize the tensors and perform a TDOT, 79 isn't possible to call a TDOT so it uses einsum loops.

Answer (score 3):

Even when used in a small loop `tensordot` is more than 10x faster:

```
timeit(lambda:np.einsum('ijkl,lui->jkui', A, B, optimize="optimal"),number=5)/5
# 3.052245747600682
timeit(lambda:np.stack([np.tensordot(a,b,1) for a,b in zip(A,B.transpose(2,0,1))],-1),number=10)/10
# 0.23842503569903784

out_td = np.stack([np.tensordot(a,b,1) for a,b in zip(A,B.transpose(2,0,1))],-1)
out_es = np.einsum('ijkl,lui->jkui', A, B, optimize="optimal")
np.allclose(out_td,out_es)
# True
```