# How do I broadcast other dimensions using numpy.matmul?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, matrix

I have an 640x480 RGB image with numpy shape (480, 640, 3) -- 3 for the R, G, B channels
and I would like to at **each pixel**, transform the RGB value according to:

```
    # for each pixel
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            # set the new RGB value at that pixel to
            # (new RGB vector) = (const matrix A) * (old RGB vector) + (const vector B)
            img[i,j,:] = np.reshape((np.matmul(A, np.expand_dims(img[i,j,:], axis = 1)) + B), (3,))
```

Where A is of shape (3,3) and B is of shape (3,1).
How do I do this with numpy without writing a loop over the pixels?

Comment: Your code doesn't work. `numpy.matmul(A, data[i,j,:].T) + B` returns shape (3,3) while `img[i,j,:]` has shape (3,). You assign shape `(3,3)` to `(3,)`.

Comment: @wuxiekeji Seemed like a typo - B must be `1D` array?

Comment: I edited it in a way that I think it works, but either way, the intention is to do (constant matrix A)*(rgb vector) + (constant vector B) at each rgb pixel.

Comment: @wuxiekeji Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be with [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
img = np.einsum('ij,klj->kli',A,data) + B
```

Another with [`np.tensordot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
img = np.tensordot(data,A,axes=(-1,-1)) + B
```

Related - [Understanding tensordot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/understanding-tensordot)

I assumed `B` to be `1D` array. If not so, use `B.ravel()` in place of `B`.

Comment: `data@A.T+B` should do the same as your `einsum` expression.