# How to select numpy tensordot axes

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

I have two numpy arrays of shape `(436, 1024, 2)`. The last dimension (`2`) represents 2D vectors. I want to compare the 2D vector of the two numpy arrays element-wise in order to find the average angular error.

To do so I want to use the dot product which works perfectly fine when looping over the two first dimensions of the arrays (`for` loop in python can be slow). Therefore I would like to use a numpy function.

I found that `np.tensordot` allows to perform dot product element-wise. However, I do not succeed to use its `axes` argument:

```py
import numpy as np

def average_angular_error_vec(estimated_oc : np.array, target_oc : np.array):
    estimated_oc = np.float64(estimated_oc)
    target_oc = np.float64(target_oc)

    norm1 = np.linalg.norm(estimated_oc, axis=2)
    norm2 = np.linalg.norm(target_oc, axis=2)
    norm1 = norm1[..., np.newaxis]
    norm2 = norm2[..., np.newaxis]

    unit_vector1 = np.divide(estimated_oc, norm1)
    unit_vector2 = np.divide(target_oc, norm2)

    dot_product = np.tensordot(unit_vector1, unit_vector2, axes=2)
    angle = np.arccos(dot_product)

    return np.mean(angle)
```

I have the following error :

```
ValueError: shape-mismatch for sum
```

Below is my function which computes the average angular error correctly:

```py
def average_angular_error(estimated_oc : np.array, target_oc : np.array):
    h, w, c = target_oc.shape
    r = np.zeros((h, w), dtype="float64")

    estimated_oc = np.float64(estimated_oc)
    target_oc = np.float64(target_oc)

    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):

            unit_vector_1 = estimated_oc[i][j] / np.linalg.norm(estimated_oc[i][j])
            unit_vector_2 = target_oc[i][j] / np.linalg.norm(target_oc[i][j])
            dot_product = np.dot(unit_vector_1, unit_vector_2)

            angle = np.arccos(dot_product)

            r[i][j] = angle
       
    return np.mean(r)
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/understanding-tensordot/41871402)

Comment: By the way, the class is `np.ndarray`. `np.array` is a static constructor. If you want to use duck-typing, stick `x = np.asanyarray(x)` or so into the start of your functions.

Comment: @JavaiMaster. The linked question is not a duplicate. It acutally explains why `tensordot` is definitely *not* the answer here.

Comment: @JavaiMaster. That being said, I feel like I've answered something like this before. I'll try to find the dupe now that I've answered it :)

Comment: @AlixL Where are you getting the error exactly? It looks more like a shape mismatch in the input than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely much simpler than you are making it. If you apply `np.tensordot` to a pair of arrays of shape `(w, h, 2)` along the last axis, you will get a result of shape `(w, h, w, h)`. This is not what you want. There are three simple approaches here. In addition to showing the options, I've shown a few tips and tricks for making the code simpler without changing any of the basic functionality:

1. Do the sum-reduction manually (using `+` and `*`):

   ```
   def average_angular_error(estimated_oc : np.ndarray, target_oc : np.ndarray):
       # If you want to do in-place normalization, do x /= ... instead of x = x / ...
       estimated_oc = estimated_oc / np.linalg.norm(estimated_oc, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
       target_oc = target_oc / np.linalg.norm(target_oc, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
       # Use plain element-wise multiplication
       dots = np.sum(estimated_oc * target_oc, axis=-1)
       return np.arccos(dots).mean()
   ```
2. Use `np.matmul` (a.k.a. `@`) with properly broadcasted dimensions:

   ```
   def average_angular_error(estimated_oc : np.ndarray, target_oc : np.ndarray):
       estimated_oc = estimated_oc / np.linalg.norm(estimated_oc, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
       target_oc = target_oc / np.linalg.norm(target_oc, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
       # Matrix multiplication needs two dimensions to operate on
       dots = estimated_oc[..., None, :] @ target_oc[..., :, None]
       return np.arccos(dots).mean()
   ```

   `np.matmul` and `np.dot` both require the last dimension of the first array to match the second to last of the second, like with normal matrix multiplication. `None` is an alias for `np.newaxis`, which introduces a new axis of size 1 at the location of your choice. In this case, I made the first array `(w, h, 1, 2)` and the second `(w, h, 2, 1)`. That ensures that the last two dimensions are multiplied as a transposed vector and a regular vector at every corresponding element.
3. Use `np.einsum`:

   ```
   def average_angular_error(estimated_oc : np.ndarray, target_oc : np.ndarray):
       estimated_oc = estimated_oc / np.linalg.norm(estimated_oc, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
       target_oc = target_oc / np.linalg.norm(target_oc, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
       # Matrix multiplication needs two dimensions to operate on
       dots = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ik', estimated_oc, target_oc)
       return np.arccos(dots).mean()
   ```

You can't use `np.dot` or `np.tensordot` for this. `dot` and `tensordot` keep the untouched dimensions of both arrays, as explained earlier. `matmul` broadcasts them together, which is what you want.

Comment: Indeed other options work very well and I found my way using np.einsum. However I still wonder how one could use np.tensordot to obtain the same result.

Would you mind explaining the np.matmul option. I am not sure to understand what [..., None, :] means. Are you adding a dimension ? If yes, why using a column after ?

Comment: @AlixL. I've fleshed out #2 and added a little postscript to address your concerns.