# How to do this np.tensordot operation in np.einsum

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

So I wanted to do the following with two 4-dimensional arrays (a and b)

```
np.tensordot(a,b, axes = ([1,2,3], [0,1,2]))
```

But I was curious how this could be done using

`np.einsum` instead

Comment: `[1,2,3], [0,1,2]` 'ijkl, jklm->im'

Comment: Refer to these answers for better understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/understanding-tensordot#:~:text=tensordot%20swaps%20axes%20and%20reshapes,to%20experiment%20than%20to%20explain.

Comment: How does this fail in the earlier numpy version.  I'm not aware of recent changes in tensodot.

Comment: Yeah sorry this ended up being false, it seemed to be something do with my virtual environment or how TensorFlow tensors handle being given to np.tensedot (in newer version I think it converts to Numpy before being used automatically, while in older versions it does not). I will edit the question