# python: Multiply slice i of a matrix stack by column i of a matrix efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
M,N,R = 2,3,4

# For a 3-dimensional array A:
A = np.reshape(np.r_[0:M*N*R], [M,N,R], order = 'C')

# and 2-dimensional array B:
B = np.reshape(np.r_[0:M*R], [R,M], order = 'C')
```

I would like the `N*M` matrix that results from multiplying slice `i` of `A` by column `i` of `B`. I have tried `np.dot`, and `np.einsum` and have been unable to obtain what I need.

Could anybody help, please? Thanks!

Comment: Did posted solution work for you?

Comment: Yes thank you! I tried posting as soon as you replied but was unable to for some reason. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), we would have -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ki->ji',A,B)
```

Let's verify the results using the given sample and using matrix-multiplication with `np.dot` -

```
In [35]: A.shape
Out[35]: (2, 3, 4)

In [36]: B.shape
Out[36]: (4, 2)

In [37]: A[0].dot(B[:,0])
Out[37]: array([ 28,  76, 124])

In [38]: A[1].dot(B[:,1])
Out[38]: array([226, 290, 354])

In [39]: np.einsum('ijk,ki->ji',A,B)
Out[39]: 
array([[ 28, 226],
       [ 76, 290],
       [124, 354]])
```

For aspects related to when to use `einsum` over `dot-based` tools like `np.dot`/`np.tensordot`, here's a [`related post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443444/numpy-element-wise-dot-product).