# Apply function along axis over two numpy arrays - shapes not aligned

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm probably not seeing something obvious here but don't believe `np.apply_along_axis` or `np.apply_over_axes` is what I'm looking for.  Say I have the following two arrays:

```
arr1 = np.random.randn(10, 5)
arr2 = np.random.randn(10, )
```

And the following function:

```
def coefs(x, y):
    return np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(x.T, x)), np.dot(x.T, y))
    # the vector of coefficients in a multiple linear regression
```

Calling this on `arr1` and `arr2` works smoothly as it should:

```
coefs(arr1, arr2)
Out[111]: array([-0.19474836, -0.50797551,  0.82903805,  0.06332607, -0.26985597])
```

However, suppose instead of the 1- or 2d arrays I have two 3d arrays:

```
arr3 = np.array([arr1[:-1], arr1[1:]])
arr4 = np.array([arr2[:-1], arr2[1:]])
```

As expected, if I apply the function here I get

```
coefs(arr3, arr4)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-127-4a3e7df02cda>", line 1, in <module>
    coefs(arr3, arr4)

  File "<ipython-input-124-7532b8516784>", line 2, in coefs
    return np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(x.T, x)), np.dot(x.T, y))

ValueError: shapes (5,9,2) and (2,9,5) not aligned: 2 (dim 2) != 9 (dim 1)
```

...because NumPy is treating each array as an object as it should.  What I want to do instead is apply the `coefs()` function to each of the 2 elements along the 0 axis of the arrays, element-wise.  Here's a crude way of doing this:

```
tgt = []
for i, j in zip(arr3, arr4):
    tgt.append(coefs(i, j))

np.array(tgt) 
Out[136]: 
array([[-0.34328006, -0.99116672,  1.42757897, -0.06687851, -0.44669182],
       [ 0.44494495, -0.58017705,  0.75825944,  0.18795889,  0.4560851 ]])
```

**My question is, is there a more efficient and pythonic way of doing this than using zip and iterating over, as above?**  Basically, given two input arrays of shape (2, n, k) and (2, n), I want the array that is returned to be of shape (2, k).  Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think `arr2` has shape 10x5?

Comment: Would the first axis length of the `3D` arrays always be `2` like you have for `arr3` and for the `2D` array `arr4`?

Comment: @user2357112 You're right, typo on my part.

Comment: @Divakar Short answer is no, I'd like to generalize this just so that the resulting array's first axis length maintains the first axis length of arr3 and arr4.

Comment: @BradSolomon Kool. Check out the posted solution that achieves the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generic shaped `3D` and `2D` arrays - `arr3` and `arr4`, we can use some [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) magic to have a vectorized solution, like so -

```
dot1 = np.einsum('ijk,ijl->ikl',arr3,arr3)
dot2 = np.einsum('ijk,ij->ik',arr3,arr4)
inv1 = np.linalg.inv(dot1)
tgt_out = np.einsum('ijk,ij->ik',inv1, dot2)
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def org_app(arr3, arr4):
    tgt = []
    for i, j in zip(arr3, arr4):
        tgt.append(coefs(i, j))
    return np.array(tgt)

def einsum_app(arr3, arr4):
    dot1 = np.einsum('ijk,ijl->ikl',arr3,arr3)
    dot2 = np.einsum('ijk,ij->ik',arr3,arr4)
    inv1 = np.linalg.inv(dot1)
    return np.einsum('ijk,ij->ik',inv1, dot2)
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [215]: arr3 = np.random.rand(50,50,50)
     ...: arr4 = np.random.rand(50,50)
     ...: 

In [216]: np.allclose(org_app(arr3, arr4), einsum_app(arr3, arr4))
Out[216]: True

In [217]: %timeit org_app(arr3, arr4)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.82 ms per loop

In [218]: %timeit einsum_app(arr3, arr4)
100 loops, best of 3: 19.7 ms per loop
```

Doesn't look like `einsum` is giving us any benefits here. This is expected because basically `einsum` is fighting it out against `np.dot`, which is much better at `sum-reduction` and even though we are using it in a loop. The only situation/case in which we can give `np.dot` a fight is when we loop enough and that should make `einsum` competitive. We are looping for times equal to the length equal of the first axis of the input arrays. Let's increase it and test again -

```
In [219]: arr3 = np.random.rand(1000,10,10)
     ...: arr4 = np.random.rand(1000,10)
     ...: 

In [220]: %timeit org_app(arr3, arr4)
10 loops, best of 3: 23 ms per loop

In [221]: %timeit einsum_app(arr3, arr4)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.1 ms per loop
```

`einsum` definitely winning on this one!

[`This related post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41443497/3293881) on the fight between `np.einsum` and `np.dot` is worth a look.

Also, note that if we need to use the loop based approach, we should look to initialize the output array and then assign the output values from `coefs` into it rather than appending, as the latter is a slow process.