# More efficient way to multiply each column of a 2-d matrix by each slice of a 3-d matrix

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have an 8x8x25000 array W and an 8 x 25000 array r. I want to multiple each 8x8 slice of W by each column (8x1) of r and save the result in Wres, which will end up being an 8x25000 matrix.

I am accomplishing this using a for loop as such:

```
for i in range(0,25000):
    Wres[:,i] = np.matmul(W[:,:,i],res[:,i])
```

But this is slow and I am hoping there is a quicker way to accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any example input / output you can share?

Comment: See also [Numpy element-wise dot product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443444/numpy-element-wise-dot-product/41443497#41443497)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matmul can propagate as long as the 2 arrays share the same 1 axis length. From the docs:

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.

Thus, you have to perform 2 operations prior to `matmul`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(8,8,100)
b = np.random.rand(8, 100)
```

1. transpose `a` and `b` so that the first axis are the 100 slices
2. add an extra dimension to `b` so that `b.shape = (100, 8, 1)`

Then:

```
 at = a.transpose(2, 0, 1) # swap to shape 100, 8, 8
 bt = b.T[..., None] # swap to shape 100, 8, 1
 c = np.matmul(at, bt)
```

`c` is now `100, 8, 1`, reshape back to `8, 100`:

```
 c = np.squeeze(c).swapaxes(0, 1)
```

or

```
 c = np.squeeze(c).T
```

---

And last, a one-liner just for conveniende:

```
c = np.squeeze(np.matmul(a.transpose(2, 0, 1), b.T[..., None])).T
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using `np.matmul` is `np.einsum`, which can be accomplished in 1 shorter and arguably more palatable line of code with no method chaining.

Example arrays:

```
np.random.seed(123)
w = np.random.rand(8,8,25000)
r = np.random.rand(8,25000)
wres = np.einsum('ijk,jk->ik',w,r)

# a quick check on result equivalency to your loop
print(np.allclose(np.matmul(w[:, :, 1], r[:, 1]), wres[:, 1]))
True
```

Timing is equivalent to @Imanol's solution so take your pick of the two.  Both are 30x faster than looping.  Here, `einsum` will be competitive because of the size of the arrays.  With arrays larger than these, it would likely win out, and lose for smaller arrays.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443444/numpy-element-wise-dot-product/41443497#41443497) discussion for more.

```
def solution1():
    return np.einsum('ijk,jk->ik',w,r)

def solution2():
    return np.squeeze(np.matmul(w.transpose(2, 0, 1), r.T[..., None])).T

def solution3():
    Wres = np.empty((8, 25000))
    for i in range(0,25000):
        Wres[:,i] = np.matmul(w[:,:,i],r[:,i])
    return Wres

%timeit solution1()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.51 ms per loop

%timeit solution2()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop

%timeit solution3()
10 loops, best of 3: 64.2 ms per loop
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988546/apply-function-along-axis-over-two-numpy-arrays-shapes-not-aligned) to: @Divakar