# vectorized/broadcasted Dot product of numpy arrays with different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

**The Problem:**

I want to calculate the dot product of a very large set of data. I am able to do this in a nested for-loop, but this is way too slow.
Here is a small example:

```
import numpy as np

points = np.array([[0.5, 2, 3, 5.5, 8, 11], [1, 2, -1.5, 0.5, 4, 5]])
lines = np.array([[0, 2, 4, 6, 10, 10, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0]])
x1 = lines[0][0:-1]
y1 = lines[1][0:-1]
L1 = np.asarray([x1, y1])

# calculate the relative length of the projection
# of each point onto each line
a = np.diff(lines)
b = points[:,:,None] - L1[:,None,:]
print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)

[rows, cols, pages] = np.shape(b)
Z = np.zeros((cols, pages))
for k in range(cols):
    for l in range(pages):
        Z[k][l] = a[0][l]*b[0][k][l] + a[1][l]*b[1][k][l]

N = np.linalg.norm(a, axis=0)**2
relativeProjectionLength = np.squeeze(np.asarray(Z/N))
```

In this example, the first two dimensions of both a and b represent the x- and y-coordinates that I need for the dot product.
The shape of a is (2,7) and b has (2,6,7). Since the dot product reduces the first dimension I would expect the result to be of the shape (6,7). How can I calculate this without the slow loops?

**What I have tried:**

I think that numpy.dot with correct broadcasting could do the job, however I have trouble setting up the dimensions correctly.

```
a = a[:, None, :]
Z = np.dot(a,b)
```

This on gives me the following error:

> shapes (2,1,7) and (2,6,7) not aligned: 7 (dim 2) != 6 (dim 1)

Comment: The kind of broadcasting that works with element wise operations like `+` and `*` does not apply to `np.dot`.  It has its own rules for matching axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,ikj->kj',a,b)
```

Explanation :

- Keep the last axes aligned for the two inputs.
- Sum-reduce the first from those.
- Let the rest stay, which is the second axis of `b`.

[Usual rules on whether to use `einsum` or stick to a `loopy-dot` based method apply here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41443497/).

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. It did the job perfectly. I find the notation of np.einsum very intuitive, as one sees directly which dimensions are reduced! The runtime analysis of different approaches will also make it to my bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) does not reduce the first dimension. From the docs:

> For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of *a* and the second-to-last of *b*:
>
> ```
> dot(a, b)[i,j,k,m] = sum(a[i,j,:] * b[k,:,m])
> ```

That is exactly what the error is telling you: it is attempting to match axis 2 in the first vector to axis 1 in the second.

You can fix this using [`numpy.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) or better yet [`numpy.moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html). Instead of `a = a[:, None, :]`, do

```
a = np.movesxis(a, 0, -1)
b = np.moveaxis(b, 0, -2)
Z = np.dot(a, b)
```

Better yet, you can construct your arrays to have the correct shape up front. For example, transpose `lines` and do `a = np.diff(lines, axis=0)`.