# Numpy vectorized combination of hadamard and dot product

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

The problem:

I have two sets of data, A and B, of shapes **k x n x m** and **k x m x p** respectively, with **k**, **m** and **p** potentially very large, and hence I'd really like to vectorize any processes upon them.

I'd like to form the dot product between these two datasets such that each **kth** element in A is dotted with each **kth** element in B (to form a **k x n x p** matrix, dotting over the mth axis). At first glance, it looked to me like a combination of hadamard product and dot product (hence the title), but I can't figure out a way to get my desired result.

As reference, because I can't get the vectorization to work well, I'm currently running it like this:

```
        for b, w in zip(biasList, weightsList):
            z = np.asarray([np.dot(weightMatrix,activation) for weightMatrix, activation in zip(w,activation)])
```

Which obviously isn't vectorized, so has terrible performance.

Using either numpy dot or numpy einsum (as shown here: [vectorized/broadcasted Dot product of numpy arrays with different dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138133/vectorized-broadcasted-dot-product-of-numpy-arrays-with-different-dimensions)) do not give me the desired results, as they seem to only bring matrices of shapes **k x n x m** and **k x m x p** together by summing over a pair of indices, yielding a matrix of size **k x n x k x p**, or over both indices, yielding **n x p**.

Is there a good way to effectively vectorize this?

Comment: `np.matmul(A,B)` or `A@B`?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give them a go and see whether it works

Comment: @Divakar, that solves it. I didn't know these methods existed - thank you for pointing it out!